# Eclipse emulator doesn't run with high resolution 2080x1536

Tags: android, eclipse, screen-resolution

I am trying to run an emulator with Eclipse with 2080x1536 resolution. I set the ram size to 500-1024MB but it just want to start. I only get the black screen.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What emulator?  Is the heap size even an issue?

Comment: heap size is set to 48

Comment: Anybody at all? Help?

Comment: Resolution should be supported by your screen, and also proper graphics drivers are to be installed to get the system resolutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get a 1080x1920 emulator running by checking the 'Use Host GPU' option in 'Emulation Options' box. You get there via the 'Edit' button for an AVD.

Before, only got a black screen...

HTH!